# Removing innerHTML img element completely

Tags: javascript, html

```
typebox.innerHTML += "<div class='typebox'><img id='typeImg' width='30px' height='30px' src="+d[o].src+"></div>";
```

I am using `innerHTML` to add multiple images, and I need those images to be removed by clicking on a remove button, but I can't figure out how to do this.

I have tried:

```
var typebox = document.getElementById("typebox");
typebox.style.display = 'none';
```

Using `display:none;` makes those images not show at all.

```
var typebox = document.getElementById("typebox");
typebox.innerHTML = "";
```

It seems like it won't remove those images, more like doing nothing at all.

So how should I remove those images completely?

Comment: `innetHTML` typo should be `innerHTML`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

> [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) will help in this case

```js
var typebox = document.getElementById('typebox');
typebox.innerHTML += "<div class='typebox'><img id='typeImg' width='300px' height='300px' src='https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'></div>";
document.getElementById('removeBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var toRemove = document.getElementById('typeImg');
    toRemove.parentNode.removeChild(toRemove);
});
```

```html
<div id='typebox'></div>
<button id='removeBtn'>remove</button>
```

> I hope this helps..

Comment: the img still there , it wont be remove.

Comment: it work if i added the full code , is there any way i can do that just by click on a button ? i dont wanted to set timer.

Comment: isit becauase it had added the addEventListener ? thank is all i wanted. thank again my friend.

Comment: This is not ideal: all the `<div class='typebox'>` will remain inside `<div id='typebox'></div>`...

Comment: @RayonDabre You will end up with this code: `<div id='typebox'><div class='typebox'></div><div class='typebox'></div><div class='typebox'></div></div>` because you remove the `<img>` node but not its parent node`<div class='typebox'>` ;-)

Comment: @laruiss, If you go through the comments, **This is what op wanted**

Comment: @RayonDabre Well I just point out that it is not an ideal situation to end up with useless nodes, if it is OK with everyone, then don't mind me.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code:

1) document.getElementById(), as it reads, get element by... `id`, not class

So given your code

```
typebox.innerHTML += "<div class='typebox'><img id='typeImg' width='30px' height='30px' src='"+d[o].src+"'></div>";
```

You should use `document.getElementByClassName('typebox')`, and it will return an array-like object (HTMLCollection or NodeList) with all the elements of the page hwich have the class 'typebox'

2) There should be only one element with a particular value in its `id` attribute

Therefore if you are using this code several times, you will have trouble getting the images:

```
typebox.innerHTML += "<div class='typebox'><img id='typeImg' width='30px' height='30px' src="+d[o].src+"></div>";
```

because there will be several `<img>` tag with the same `id`

If you want to delete all the images and their wrappers:

```
var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('typebox'));
elements.forEach(function (element) {
    element.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(element.parentNode);
);
```

Comment: oh is what i wanted , i know server img adding tag in same id will cause problem , that why i trying to remove and re add , by the way i cant make the code work , it didt remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `'`, and also `innetHTML` should be `innerHTML`... Change your code to this:

```
typebox.innerHTML += "<div class='typebox'><img id='typeImg' width='30px' height='30px' src='"+d[o].src+"'></div>";

var typebox = document.getElementById("typebox");
typebox.innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: tryed cant remove those img.

Answer (score 0):

Just use html() method for complete removing image. (In case of jquery)

You code is also ok but following line has the problem

```
typebox.innetHTML = "";
```

just replace the above line with

```
typebox.innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `removeChild()` method of JavaScript to do this. See the code below :

```
function deleteDiv(){
var myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("typebox")[0];
document.removeChild(myDiv);
}
```

**Explanation:**

The first line gets an element with a `class` of 'typebox' and assigns it to a variable called `myDiv`.

The second lines removes the `div` from the body.

> See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) for reference of `removeChild()`.